Ever since I stopped punishing my puppy for pooping inside, the house training has gotten worse
My dog is 7 months old I started house training her about two months ago because it's been winter and she has been too cold and afraid to go outside. She had gotten pretty good With the house training, she still had accidents A few times a week or so, but she still knew that she wasn't supposed to poop inside because I punished her every time she did. I could not get her to stop having accidents until the other day when she had a massive poop on my bed. I went online and they told me. that I'm not supposed to be punishing her and that if I stop punishing her, she will learn not to poop inside somehow. So about a week ago I stopped punishing her when she had accidents inside and the a number of accidents have grown. She poops anywhere indiscriminately. She doesn't even bother pooping when we go outside anymore. She'd rather just do it in the house. I can't stand outside until she goes #2 because she doesn't have to poop every time we go for a walk, which we do every two and a half hours or so.
Basically, when I punished her, she knew that she wasn't supposed to be going inside. Now that I don't punish her, she has no sense that going inside is not good, and she just does it indiscriminately anywhere. She doesn't wait till we go outside. And yes, when she does go outside, I throw her a party and I give her the good treats. She doesn't seem to be motivated by them. She's not devising ways to get the good treats and have a party. She doesn't seem to care enough for that to be something that directs her to hold her waste in order to get them.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

When did you visit the vet last time? Did you mention the problem there? In general dogs want to please. So you should rule out any health issue...

How long does it take for you to take the dog out? Is it as quick as opening the door to your own backyard or do you have to walk 3 halls and take an elevator or something similar? Do you have access to a calm place outside or is it all busy roads? Dogs do have a certain body language when they seek a place to poop, but honestly it's not easy to spot. In an ideal world you would spot that sign and immediately take her out every time right before she poops.
